# Remove reliance on entity framework context naming?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I teach a basic programming class in .Net MVC (v4.5) that requires they use SQL Server as a backend and EF5.  In order to simplify matters I have the students use database first code generation.  The issue is that often they run into problems related to moving solutions around, sharing code, and changing the database from local to remote (Azure).  This results in changes to the context class name or the connection string (or both) which causes all sorts of problems, as you can imagine.

While I can work with each student and fix their issues and have explained the code along with the consequences of changes numerous times it is very time consuming.

Knowing that this is supposed to be an introductory class I am reluctant to teach too much about interfaces and abstraction and I'm not even certain this would fix their issues anyway.  Other thoughts are to do the work myself to create the interface and just have them use it.  Or, probably most simply, just require they use the same name every time as new solutions are created (which I have stressed).

To be fair, it's not that all students are having these issues but in a classroom the "[squeaky wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_squeaky_wheel_gets_the_grease)" syndrome is alive and well and it takes too much personal time to keep readdressing.

At the risk of this question being too broad, does anyone know of a pattern or technique I could have them implement to avoid the issue of context or connection string naming issues caused from changes?

Comment: What kind of problems do they come up against when they change the connection string or the context name?  Both of those things should be a breeze.  The context name, I assume you mean the DbContext name (?) shouldn't make any difference at all to the compilation and as long as the connection string is correct for their environment it should just connect.

Comment: Because they used the wizard to create the code, the class name in Context.cs can be variable as well as the connection string name in the base(name=) constructor.  I've explained this to them numerous times but there are some who will never understand.

Comment: Oh sugar, I'm sorry, I misread what you said and thought you said 'code first', whoops!  Yes, I guess with the auto code generation thing it could be tricky.  Talking of though - I wonder if doing it database first isn't a way of making things less complicated, maybe doing it code first could be less complicated?  At least then there is less scope  changes to the model or DbContext without them being done manually by the student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not to be over-critical here, but the problems would relieve themselves if you weren't having them rely on Database First. The EDMX junk is a perennial issue for new and old developers alike. It's probably one of the largest blunders the EF team ever made. Thankfully, they've worked to correct that. Code First was introduced in EF 4.1 to provide a better way, and now, EF 6 is actually the last version to ever support EDMX, including the Database First and Model First patterns, as both have been deprecated.

The thing is that Code First was named in contradiction to the existing Database First and Model First patterns, but despite the name, it has *always* been able to work with existing databases, in addition to creating new ones. There's [more information on my blog](https://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/), if you're interested. The point is that if your goal is to have your students design a database first, that doesn't preclude still using Code First, and in fact, you're doing your students a disservice by teaching them to use a methodology that is deprecated, instead.

Comment: I appreciate the comment and completely agree to much of your points.  The fact is that I do use code first here at work and am aware of the deprecation.  I spend a lot of time in class showing what has been generated but the hope was to get them up and running quickly with a minimum of fuss.  This has not been super successful.  In my defense I am picking up this curriculum from another instructor and attempting to improve on it.  Given your feedback I'll consider how to best teach them code first moving forward.

Comment: Sounds like your hate for EDMX goes deep. Having a designer to map a subset of your schema into a model where you can visually inspect included columns and relations has been a blessing for many people, especially when working with predefined, unalterable databases. Yes, EDMX causes a hell in source control and broke more easily than it was fixed (changing a column from non-nullable to nullable or vice versa, or renaming a foreign key? Good luck...), but it did have its place.

Comment: Thanks also for the blog post.  Just to be clear, the issue surrounds "public ApplicationContext() : base("ConnectionStringName")" and, despite my numerous explanations, they have issues with modifying this code.  Perhaps it's the mindset driven by the database-first mentality.  In any case, thanks again.

Comment: They should never need to modify the connection string *name*, which is what's used there. To move from Dev to Prod, they should be using config transforms to alter the actual connection string.

Comment: I have a deep hatred for WYSIWYGs in general. Almost invariably they promote a persistent ignorance of concepts that are mandatory for a good developer to know. They may have a place in onboarding new devs, but they end up doing more harm than good, because those new devs are never really encouraged to move past it. I tend to have a stricter view of such things, admittedly. Personally, I'd say if you can't grasp how to create a class by hand that maps to a database table, programming simply may not be your bag.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  In one of the many rants I'm known for in class I've actually said as much.  My blunt statement of "if you don't find this fascinating or won't do the work to understand how it's working means you probably won't succeed as a developer" was met equally with laughs and groans.  Not surprisingly many of the groaners did not make it through the entire class.

Comment: In fact, I can almost assure they won't succeed as a developer. When I'm interviewing devs, the first thing I look for is something that shows they've learned something on their own. They could have a PhD in Comp Sci, but if that's all they have, it's not enough. What you learn in college concerning programming has a shelf-life that pretty much expires the minute the degree is put in your hand.

Answer (score 0):

> This results in changes to the context class name or the connection string (or both) which causes all sorts of problems, as you can imagine.

A simple workaround is to explain the two things at play here:

- Instantiating a DbContext-derived class, and
- Passing it the name of a connection string present in the configuration

They should know that in order to instantiate an object, they need to know its type name. So whatever they call their DbContext-derived class, they should note this name down and make sure the rest of their code uses it.

So if they name it `Net101Databases` or `MyCoolFirstDbContext`, you'll have to stress that they use `using (var context = new`**`TheirContextName()`**`)` in order to be able to use it.

Secondly, you can trivially add a constructor overload that accepts a connection string name and passes that to the base class:

```
public ApplicationContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString) 
{ }
```

And now they can instantiate it using the connection string name as found in their configuration:

```
using (var context = new MyCooolFirstAzureContext("AzureConnectionString"))
{
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your detail in explaining the issues.  To your first point, I have explained exactly this with slides and code and demonstrations on how the errors occur, attempting to focus on the consequences.  I do like your idea of using the constructor in place of the traditional `using()` statement.  Thanks much for the idea.